# Registration in codeigniter

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I am trying to register  in the following code. But when i register i got the error message  undefined variable base.

View:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $base?>/<?php echo $css?>/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $base?>/<?php echo $css?>/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="<?php echo $base."/".$js?>/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $base."/".$js?>/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $base."/".$js?>/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title>Registration</title>
</head>
```

Config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ASOFT/Projects/CG_Pack';
$config['site_url'] = 'http://localhost/ASOFT/Projects/CG_Pack/index.php';
$config['css'] = 'assets/css';
$config['js'] = 'assets/js';
$config['image'] = 'assets/image';
```

Controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Home extends CI_Controller {
    var $data;
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct(); 
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->model('user_model');
        $this->data = array(
        'site' => $this->config->item('site_url'),
             'base' => $this->config->item('base_url'),
             'css' => $this->config->item('css'),
            'js' => $this->config->item('js'),
            'image'=>$this->config->item('image')
        );

    }

public function index()
    {
        $data=$this->data;  
        $this->load->view('header',$data);
        }

public function register()
{
$this->load->view('header');
}
    public function do_register()
    {
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('uname', 'Username', 'required|min_length[4]|max_length[15]');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass', 'Password', 'required|min_length[4]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('titleimg','Title','required|min_length[4]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('descrip', 'Description', 'required|min_length[4]');


    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {


            /*$this->load->view('header');  

    }
    else
    {


 $path = $_FILES['image']['name'];

 $imgext=strtolower(strrchr($path,'.'));

    $imgname= $this->generateRandomString().$imgext;

   if($path!='')
   {

   $im= $this->config->item('base_url').'/uploads'.'/'.$imgname;
   $x=$this->do_upload($imgname);

  $data['img']=$im;


    $this->user_model->register_user($data);
   $this->load->view('header',$data);

}
}
}

 function generateRandomString()
  {
     $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
     $randomString = '';
     for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
         $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
     }
     return $randomString;
  } 

        function do_upload($img)
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '1024 ';
        $config['file_name'] = $img;    
        $this->load->library('upload',$config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('image'))

        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            /*$data['error']=$error;
            return $data;*/
            return $error;

        }
        else
        {

            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
             return $data;
        }
        return;
    } 
}
```

When i register  i got the error

A PHP Error was encountered

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: base_url

Filename: views/header.php

Line Number: 6

Backtrace:

File: C:\softwares\xamp\htdocs\ASOFT\Projects\CG_Pack\application\views\header.php
Line: 6
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\softwares\xamp\htdocs\ASOFT\Projects\CG_Pack\application\controllers\home.php
Line: 22
Function: view

File: C:\softwares\xamp\htdocs\ASOFT\Projects\CG_Pack\index.php
Line: 293
Function: include_once

/assets/css/style.css">
```

Comment: In the code you commented out, in the do registration method. Did the error show when you commented it?

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing the `$data`, when you load the `header` view in the `register` method.

Try it like this:

```
public function register()
{
   $this->load->view('header', $this->data);
}
```

That should get rid of the error.

Answer (score 0):

*Instead of using base_url by config variable, you can call base_url() method so you don't have to add it in each and every controller.*

To do that you must first have the URL Helper loaded. This can be done either in application/config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Or, manually:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Once it's loaded, be sure to keep in mind that base_url() doesn't implicitly print or echo out anything, rather it returns the value to be printed:

```
echo base_url();
```

Comment: I don't think he is calling the 'base_url()' function from the url  helper.. He is creating them himself.

Answer (score 0):

Either use `base_url()` function in the view & this is the correct way to use it or make sure you are passing `$base` variable to view. I don't think you are passing any kind of data to view in the register method of your controller.